# Problems with SQL Joins on a assigment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a question for my assignment

[Data](https://courses.edx.org/asset-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YDB-SQL0001+2T2020+type@asset+block/moviedata.html)

Question: For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name and the title of the movie.

Here's what I've tried. I joined all the tables.

```
select *
from Rating 
join Reviewer on Rating.rID = Reviewer.rID
join Movie on Rating.mID = Movie.mID
```

But how to continue? If a Reviewer rated the same Movie and the last rating of this movie is higher than former, then I need to show this reviewer. But how to do it in SQL?

Comment: It would be good to know what you have tried. SO is not a code writing service and especially homework assignments.

Comment: I'd probably use `EXISTS`.

Comment: Show me the code jarl

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: Iam using SQL Server

Comment: In future please ensure your question is stand-alone, i.e. add the data as formatted text directly to the question, don't link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join what you already had with `Rating` again, so that you can get all records where the reviewer is the same and the movie is the same, then filter only rows where a record with a later `ratingDate` has more stars.

In case the same reviewer did review 3 or more times, then use `select distinct`  to remove duplicates

```
select distinct rev.name, m.title
from Rating r1
join Reviewer rev on rev.rID = r1.rID
join Movie m on m.mID = r1.mID 
join Rating r2 on r1.rID = r2.rID and r1.mID = r2.mID
where r1.ratingDate < r2.ratingDate and r1.stars < r2.stars
```

Comment: You got the row. Now I just need to understand How.

Comment: Suppose you have a row, after `join` you might get this row multiple times, joined with all other rows based on `on` condition of `join`. Joining `join Rating r2 on r1.rID = r2.rID and r1.mID = r2.mID` creates many rows, among which you filter only fitting via `where ` clause

Comment: I do not understand this line: --- where r1.ratingDate < r2.ratingDate and r1.stars < r2.stars ---

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this..

I find out the count of (rid,mid) combinations which have exactly 2 (ie two reviews by same reviewer against the same movie) this shows up as the column cnt.
After which i find the latest rating by ranking the ratingdate in desc. Thus row_number=1 gets you the latest rating value

```
with data
  as (
select count(*) over(partition by rt.rid,rt.mid) as cnt
       ,row_number() over(partition by rt.rid,rt.mid order by rt.ratindate desc) as rnk
       ,rw.name
       ,mov.title
  from rating rt
  join reviewer rw
    on rt.rid=rw.rid
  join movie mov 
    on mov.mid=rt.mid
      )
select *
  from data
 where rnk=1
   and cnt=2
```

Comment: Do you have a easier version. Its very complicate. I am new in SQL

Comment: Its using analytical functions, since you are starting with SQL i suggest you have a look at these functions count(*) over(partition by) and row_number() over(). These are very nifty functions which will aid you as you progress with your understanding

Answer (score 0):

For the cases a reviewer rated the same movie multiple times, you are interested in their first and second rating. (Possible further ratings, i.e. a reviewer rating a movie a third or fourth time etc., must get ignored.) So, number the rows (with `ROW_NUMBER`). Then see whether the second rating is higher than the first (by grouping by reviewer and movie and comparing both ratings). For the matches look up reviewer name and movie title, for which you'd normally use `where (rid, mid) in ( subquery )`, but SQL Server does not support `IN` clauses with tuples, so you'd inner join instead.

```
select r.name, m.title
from reviewer r
cross join movie m
join
(
  select rid, mid
  from
  (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by rid order by ratingdate) as rn
    from Rating 
  ) numbered
  group by rid, mid
  having max(rn) > 1
  and any_value(case when rn = 1 then stars end) <
      any_value(case when rn = 2 then stars end)
) matches on matches.rid = r.rid and matches.mid = m.mid
order by r.name, m.title;
```